# Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start because of com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, tomcat9

Tomcat9 server can't start again because this time has below error, I already follow the installation instruction from the official website using 3.12, and also I can't the jar in my classpath.

However, it works previously until now. what other MongoDB dependencies I should add?

I also use Java 1.8 JDK for run time.

Error message below,

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myWebsite]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    ... 40 more
```

my dependencies in the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.7</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.7</version>
    </dependency>

// below are other dependcies    
</dependencies>
```

[image]

Comment: your application which is being deployed at tomcat should havea  jar containing these classes `com.mongodb.client.*`

Comment: I was just using maven to put all relevant dependencies to run the server, but it strange it works previously. Where can I download these and add them in?

Comment: it is not a tomcat issue as far as i see, please post you application pom file do a clean package and then install, in the generated war/jar file please check where mongo client classes are present or using using zip extractor

Comment: Do you have resources to show the "How to" instruction from what you suggested? I don't want to mess it up... thanks

Comment: I configured Maven in the properties setting and integrate JavaEE with it. It is up and running but not sure if it is the correct process. However, the classpath still do not have the jar to show.